# PHP "header("Connection: close")" and "flush()" not working on production server

Tags: php, ajax, hosting

I’m setting up a new application in php that use output buffering, the code works fine on local server (wamp) but when I upload my code to the production server the code doesn't work,

```
<?php

ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true); // just to be safe
ob_start();
echo('Text the user will see ');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush(); // Unless both are called !
// Do processing here 
sleep(6);
echo('Text user will never see');

?>
```

I expect the output of `'Text the user will see'`, but the server doesn't close the connection,  but the actual output is `'Text the user will see Text user will never see'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751772/php-output-buffer-not-flushing

Comment: Flushing in PHP is not all here, the web server has to play along as well. // What are you actually trying to _achieve_ by this? There’s probably better solutions available.

Comment: @04FS thanks for your reply, I want to send a response to the client before the script finishes all the work

Answer (score 1):

Some servers use the FastCGI Process Manager. You may want to consider adding the [fastcgi finish request](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) to your code. From the documentation:

> This function flushes all response data to the client and finishes the request. This allows for time consuming tasks to be performed without leaving the connection to the client open.

It's however not available when the FastCGI Process Manager is not used, resulting in errors, so you may want to add it conditionally:

```
if ( function_exists("fastcgi_finish_request") ) fastcgi_finish_request();
```